# how to insert service data in compact database in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8

Iam caching the services using the database ,I am using sql server compact database (.sdf file) and copying database to isolated storage.There is a change in services so iam not able to cache it ,So how to manually insert services in.sdf file

```
         CREATE TABLE [GenContents]
            (
             [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
                    [ModuleUniqueName] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
                   [ResponseContent] NTEXT,
                   [Category] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
                       [Language] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL,
                         [StoredTime] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
                );

                ALTER TABLE [GenContents] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_GenContents] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]);
```

Comment: Which type of data are you storing? Can you please paste table structure?